# php's exec giving different result than running script in shell

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec, expect

I made an expect script to control my Mikrotik router from the shell (code below).

Running the script from the shell:

```
sudo -u www-data sh -c '/usr/bin/expect /full/path/to/Mikrotik_wifi.sh 192.168.0.1 username TopSecretPassword wlan1 status > /tmp/expect.log 2>&1'
```

Yields the expected result (wifi info after 'Wifi Status:'):

```
$ cat /tmp/expect.log
Starting SSH Connection to 192.168.0.1
Sending credentials
Logged in
Wifi Status:
 /interface wireless print where name=wlan1
Flags: X - disabled, R - running
 0  R name="wlan1" mtu=1500 mac-address=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF arp=enabled interface-type=Atheros AR9300 mode=ap-bridge ssid="SOMENAME" frequency=2412 band=2ghz-b/g
      channel-width=20mhz scan-list=default wireless-protocol=802.11 vlan-mode=no-tag vlan-id=1 wds-mode=disabled wds-default-bridge=none wds-ignore-ssid=no
      bridge-mode=disabled default-authentication=yes default-forwarding=yes default-ap-tx-limit=0 default-client-tx-limit=0 hide-ssid=no
      security-profile=WiFi-Sec compression=no
[username@APNAME] >

Logged out
```

Trying to run it from php's exec()

```
exec("sh -c '/usr/bin/expect /full/path/to/Mikrotik_wifi.sh 192.168.0.1 username TopSecretPassword wlan1 status > /tmp/expect.log 2>&1'");
echo readfile("/tmp/expect.log");
```

yeilds unexpected results in browser (missing wifi info):

```
Starting SSH Connection to 192.168.0.1
Sending credentials
Logged in
Wifi Status:

[username@APNAME] >

Logged out
```

My expect script

```
$ cat /full/path/to/Mikrotik_wifi.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set username "$username+tc80w"
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set interface [lindex $argv 3]
set command [lindex $argv 4]
set pass "password:"
set prompt "] >"

# display on screen
log_user 0

# Connect
send_user "Starting SSH Connection to $host\n"
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$host

expect "$pass";
sleep .1;
send_user "Sending credentials\n"
send "$password";
sleep .1;
send "\n";
sleep .1;

expect "$prompt";
send_user "Logged in\n"

# Perform command
switch -regexp -- $command {
    {on} {
        send "/interface wireless enable numbers=$interface"
        sleep .1
        send "\r"
      send_user "Wifi ON\n"
    }
    {off} {
        send "/interface wireless disable numbers=$interface"
        sleep .1
        send "\r"
        send_user "Wifi OFF\n"
    }
    {status} {
      send_user "Wifi Status:\n"
        send "/interface wireless print where name=$interface"
        sleep .1
        send "\r"
        expect "$prompt";
        puts $expect_out(buffer)
    }
    default {
        send_user "Please select command: on, off, status\n"
    }
}

# Logout
sleep .1;
send "/quit";
sleep .1;
send "\n";
send_user "Logged out\n"
exit
```

I have tried

- disabling the mikrotik's shell colour and size: username+tc80w (http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual%3aConsole_login_process#FAQ)
- including stderr: 2>&1
- writing to a file instead of outputting straight to browser: > /tmp/expect.log
- including the shell (sh -c) in the exec call
- tried different flavours of exec: exec, shell_exec, system, passthru
- increasing the exec buffer size: buffer 2000
- removing hidden characters from exec's $expect_out(buffer): set clean [regsub -all {[^ .,=[:alnum:]]} $lineOfBuffer ""]
- send_user vs puts makes no difference

System info

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
expect version 5.45
PHP Version 5.6.14-0+deb8u1
```

Any suggestions on how to fix/debug this ?

---

**Update (1):**

I have tried the expect script with

```
log_user 1
```

While this doesn't change the result, it gives me these symbols in the browser:

- [9999B
- [K

---

**Update (2):**

I have tried the expect script with

```
exp_internal 1
```

This gives me the following relevant output:

```
Wifi Status:
send: sending "/interface wireless print where name=wlan1" to { exp5 }
send: sending "\r" to { exp5 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "] >"? no

expect: does " \r[username@APNAME] > \u001b[K/interface wireless print where name=wlan1" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "] >"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "] >"
```

Could it be that the command is not being executed - and how could I check that (mikrotik logs won't reveal it...) - however, the wifi on/off commands work fine...

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` in the `Expect` code and share the debug info. Also, are you sure that the file redirection working properly ?

Comment: Have you tried using `send_user` instead of `puts` in line `puts$expect_out(buffer)` ??

Comment: @Dinesh - I have updated my reply based on your feedback. Regarding file redirect working: I assume you mean am I reading the correct file ? That's a yes.

Comment: @Shankar - `send_user` or `puts` make no difference